# Kafka consumer start with latest

Tags: apache-kafka

Let’s say I have a Kafka stream of some status records.

Now I want to connect multiple consumers so that:

- whenever a new consumer connects it should receive the most recent (current) status
- all connected consumers receive status updates

For the second, I guess I can put every consumer into a different group. How do I achieve the first?

Also, will Kafka go belly up if I create millions of different “random” short living consumer groups?

Comment: so you want that whenever a new consumer joins it should read the the message which has not been read yet?

Comment: @NawnitSen no, only the lastest plus all updates

Comment: as mentioned in one of the answer `auto.offset.reset = latest` along with `enable.auto.commit=false` should do that